# HowTo - Image Style's 404 image

Tags: 7, media

How could I define an image for those images that are not found (404's). In other words, if image which is displaying with image style is not found, provide an another image?

If someone is interested here is my solution:

```
function themeName_image_style($variables) {
  // Determine the dimensions of the styled image.

  $dimensions = array(
    'width' => $variables['width'],
    'height' => $variables['height'],
);

  image_style_transform_dimensions($variables['style_name'], $dimensions);

  $variables['width'] = $dimensions['width'];
  $variables['height'] = $dimensions['height'];

  // Determine the url for the styled image.
  $variables['path'] = image_style_url($variables['style_name'], $variables['path']);

  // Load default image for 404's
  if(!file_exists($variables['path'])) {
    $variables['path'] = file_create_url('/sites/all/themes/custom/lsa/css/images/404.png');
  }

  return theme('image', $variables);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about providing a default image or a default image _style_?  The question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I was asking about default image, that will be displayed if source one is not found (404).

Comment: You don't need to do this through code since the functionality is so ingrained into Drupal 7's core.  See my answer.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Your option will work only for those fields in which user *did not* upload images at all - blank fields - then will be used an provided default image. But my question was how to handle images that was uploaded to fields, but become broken (404), and only solution for this that I found - is to check, after image style generated an image URI,- if the file really exists in the file system. If not - use 404.png image.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Administration -> Structure -> Content Types, select the name of your content type, then click on Manage Fields.  Find the image field, click edit for that field, then scroll down until you see the Image Field Settings section.  Click the default image button, and select what image you want to show by default.